# Multithreading on 2 different vertica connections

Tags: python, multithreading, pyodbc, vertica

I'm writing a python script that runs multiple queries from a vertica database.  I read that vertica doesn't support this kind of concurrent processing on one database connection so I created two.  I was wondering whether someone could help me figure out why the following isn't working?  I've tested this using a single connection, but it seems like the second is causing trouble.

Thanks in advance,

Ben

```
days = range(1,31)
full_days = []
for i in days:
    a = "2015-06-" + str(i)
    full_days.append(a)

queries = []
for i in full_days:
    queries.append("select count(*) from table where date(created = " + i)


start_time = time.time()
def run_queries_diff(queries):
    print 'starting'
    x = ['DRIVER=Vertica;SERVER=vertica1;DATABASE=abc;PORT=5433;UID=;PWD=', 'DRIVER=Vertica;SERVER=vertica1;DATABASE=abc;PORT=5433;UID=;PWD=']
    conn = pyodbc.connect(x[random.randint(0,1)])
    cursor.execute(queries)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print 'done'
    return rows[0]

pool = ThreadPool(2)
results = pool.map(run_queries_diff, queries)
print time.time() - start_time
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()

    raise self._value
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
```

Comment: Have you verified you can connect via `isql`?

Comment: What's isql?  I've been able to connect using one pyodbc connection.